# Load Ubermenu Stylesheet in Header Rather Than Footer In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Recently took over managing a wordpress website, which I don't have much experience in. Wondering how I can move the Ubermenu minified css stylesheet and load that in the header rather than the footer. Since it loads in the footer, the sub menu flashes on page load and then hides. Any help on this would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to dequeue the stylesheet:

```
wp_dequeue_style( $handle )
```

Then you will need to requeue the stylesheet in the header:

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

From what I can tell from the code, all stylesheets are enqueued to the header, which suggests that your stylesheet is being loaded in some 'non standard' way inorder to get it into the footer. So you'll really need to track that down as you'll likely have to manually remove it or use other hooks to remove it rather than dequeue it.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I was reading through dequeue and enqueue, and definitely seems like that's the route. Do you have any ideas or recommendations for how I can see how the plugin is handling this? Thanks again

Comment: You could install one of the many plugins that lets you see all the hooks, then you click on each hook and see what is loaded in it. That might be time consuming. The other alternative is a quick scan through the plugin code. Or, you could use a tool such as Notepad++ that will scan multiple files. Use then do a search across the whole plugin for the name of the css file being loaded (eg mystyle.css) and that'll hopefully show you the code where the stylesheet is being loaded.

Comment: @soulglow Nice username! ;-) Please mark my answer as accepted or give it an upvote if you think it's helped you. Thanks.